# Error While Opening .pyc Files

Tags: python

Whenever I try to open .pyc or .pyo files, I always get an error that says FAILED TO DECODE.

```
OS: Lion
Python: 3.0.1
```

*I
'm trying to open them in IDLE, it asks me what the current encoding of the file is, and pre-entered is `us-ascii`*

Comment: And why exactly are you trying to open a pyc (byte-compiled python) file?

Comment: Why would you try to open a file you didn't create yourself without knowing what it's for and without already knowing how to handle such things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are compiled Python bytecode; they can be executed by the interpreter, but they are not human-readable or editable.

```
python helloworld.pyc
```